# How to run jasmine unit tests using phantom js

Tags: jasmine, phantomjs

I have got a bunch of unit tests written in jasmine for my sencha application which runs fine in browser.
so the following link works fine in my browser with all the test results

http://localhost:1841/ICFDUIUnitTest/index.html?test=user/testListUser

Now, i want to see the results in command line using phantomjs. What is the best way to do it? i have tried couple of things but it did not work properly.

I have tried loading this as a web page and try to grab the DOM elements but surprisingly, some of the DOM elements are not accesiible. The same elements are accessible in the browser

```
page.open(system.args[1], function(status){
if (status !== "success") {
    console.log("Unable to open " + system.args[1]);
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    waitFor(function(){
        return page.evaluate(function(){
            return document.body.querySelector('.symbolSummary .pending') === null;
        });
    }, function(){
        var exitCode = page.evaluate(function(){
            try {
                console.log(document.body.querySelector('.results > .failures > .description'));

            } catch (ex) {
                console.log(ex);
                return 1;
            }
        });
        phantom.exit(exitCode);
    });
}
```

});

```
console.log(document.body.querySelector('.results > .failures > .description'));
```

The above line returns null while it works in browser.

```
console.log(document.body.querySelector('.results > .failures'));
```

This line works fine in browser as well as in phantom. So, some DOM elements are accesible and some are not.

I run this test as

```
phantomjs unit.js http://localhost:1841/ICFDUIUnitTest/index.html?test=user/testListUser
```

Comment: Maybe you should find a better selector that denotes that the page has loaded. You could directly wait until `'.results > .failures > .description'` is populated. You can also try a static `setTimeout()` before working on the page.

Comment: Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.